# MYSQL-BEFORE UPDATE Set value of Column A to value in Column B if Column A is to be updated

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a nightly scheduled event which updates all rows in 'products' table with the newest 'unit_price' from a price list table where 'price_list.active-date' is >= the CURDATE(). What I need to do is create a trigger for the products table to set the field 'last_price' to the old unit_price before the update only on rows where unit_price is changing. Is this possible.

Scheduled Event:

```
CREATE EVENT `update_active_price` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS '2015-02-09 00:00:00' 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
    ENABLE COMMENT 'updates nightly at midnight' 
    DO 
        UPDATE products p 
        JOIN price_list pr ON p.product_id = pr.product_id
        SET p.unit_price = pr.amount
        WHERE active_date = CURDATE();
```

Currently non-working Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_last_price` BEFORE UPDATE ON `products`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE products p
SET p.last_price = p.unit_price;
```

Comment: Put the prices in a separate, parallel, table.  This will speed things up, possibly allow for simpler UPDATEs, and be cleaner design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the trigger's syntax

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_last_price`;
CREATE TRIGGER `update_last_price`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `products`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.last_price = OLD.unit_price;
```

or if the trigger is to have multiple lines, do this

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_last_price`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_last_price`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `products`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.last_price = OLD.unit_price;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Not quite the result I was looking for. This changes both the unit_price and the last_price to the updated value. I would like to set last_price = old unit_price and then have unit_price updated to new unit_price. Is this not possible?

Comment: I updated it with `OLD.` instead of `NEW.`